# .NET Core and Client Certificate Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I have an API that runs as a sub-application on an IIS website.  I developed the API using .NET 7 and it utilizes the Client Certificate Authentication Scheme.  I have also added some additional authorization handlers for the endpoints.

I have the website configured to require client certificates, all forms of authentication including anonymous are disabled with the exception of clientCertificateMappingAuthentication.

Because it's a .NET Core application, the application pool is set to "No Managed Code" for the CLR version.  The only modules available to the application in IIS are the Authentication and Authorization Rules.  For the application, again, all forms of authentication are disabled with the exception of clientCertificateMappingAuthentication.  The authorization rules are set to Deny Anonymous Users (the first rule) and then Allow All Users.

In my .NET framework APIs, if a user is anonymous, the request does not even make it to the API.  IIS will reject the request outright with a 401 error.

This is not the case with the .NET Core application I wrote.  The request makes it to the API, but my code rejects it with a 403 error because of the authorization handlers I have in place.

I guess my question is whether this is by design or is something wrong with my configuration of the application?

Comment: Enable FRT and compare the modules that generated the different responses and you might get some hints from there.

Comment: @LexLi what is FRT?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-php-with-failed-request-tracing

Comment: 403 is by design? We have this saying [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0#get-started). `If authentication fails, this handler returns a 403 (Forbidden) response rather a 401 (Unauthorized), as you might expect. `

Comment: @TinyWang The issue isn't whether I'm receiving a 403.  The issue was that the API was getting a hit at all.  As I mentioned in the issue description,  with .NET Framework and the IIS configuration, a user that had not authenticated with Active Directory using the clientCertificateMappingAuthentication is anonymous and IIS would reject with a 401 - meaning that the API would never even receive the request.  I was surprised to see the API actually getting hit.  Based on further research, it appears that everything is actually working as it should.

Comment: sorry for my misunderstanding.. and I don't have any other ideas then .

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to this question is that it's by design.

There were some nuances to the security within IIS that I was missing.

ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication requires the user to have a certificate, for user accounts to be in Active Directory, and for the IIS Server to be part of the Active Directory domain.  If the user presents a certificate and is found within the Active Directory domain, the user is provided with a Windows identity.  If the user is not found, I believe the user is provided a Windows identity, but that identity is marked as not authenticated and would not have all of the other additional identity properties filled in.

You must also configure the site to require SSL and to negotiate certificates. If the user does not present a certificate, IIS rejects the request with a 403 HTTP error.

This method of authentication does not prevent a user from accessing a system.  With this method of authentication, a user would still be considered anonymous if their certificate is not mapped with an account.

Once the user is authenticate (or not), for .NET Framework application, the Authorization rules kick in.  In these instances (using the ASP.NET Authorization Rules and the IIS Authorization rules), you would establish rules to Deny anonymous users and Allow all other users. Users who have not authenticated against Active Directory are anonymous and the request is rejected with a 401 HTTP error, i.e., you have authenticated but are not allowed access.

When configuring .NET Core, you configure the Application Pool with the "No Managed Code" option for the CLR type.  This means the only options available for configuration in IIS are the IIS options.  You can configure the Authorization Rules option in IIS.  However, my understanding is that the only requests impacted by these rules are for static files.  Requests for a .NET Core application are handled independently of these rules.

Therefore, it is possible for a user who is, according to Active Directory, anonymous to access an endpoint in the API.

Endpoints in .NET Framework and Core are accessible to anonymous and authenticated users alike.  Authorization code is key in all applications to reject users who should not have access to your application.  You are on the hook for authorizing the users instead of having IIS doing it for you at the top level with the Authorization Rules module.

In .NET Core you can decorate your endpoints with [AllowAnonymous] to bypass authorization requirements.  If you're using the Minimal API, you would use the AllowAnonymous when defining your endpoint.

The logic behind .NET Core operating independently of the rules defined in the Authorization Rules module makes sense because of all of the various ways to authenticate and authorize a user now.  I could see how having blanket rules defined at the top level and, which are inherited, could interfere with access to an application.

I think this about covers everything.